# Wrong matrix size in dot product multiplication with sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am coding a linear regression. I have issues with the `.dot()` product when used with SciPy sparse matrices. Here is a minimal reproducible example with 200 observations, 50 regressors, and 400 outputs.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

n_row = 200
n_col = 50
n_outcomes = 400

x = np.random.rand(n_row, n_col)

y = scipy.sparse.rand(n_row, n_outcomes, format="csc", density=0.05)

print(x.shape)  # (200, 50)
print(y.shape)  # (200, 400)
print((x.T @ y).shape) # (50, 400)
print(((x.T).dot(y)).shape)  # (50, 200) <- WRONG, it should be (50, 400)
xx_inv = np.linalg.inv(x.T.dot(x))
xx_inv.dot((x.T).dot(y)) # this calculation takes a long time
```

Reading [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), it says that that for 2-D matrices, `.dot()` is like matrix multiplication `@`, but using `@` works.

What does `.dot()` do with sparse matrices, and why does it do it instead of throwing an error?

Comment: If you create a dense matrix instead of using scipy sparse, does that work as expected?

Comment: `y = np.random.random((n_row, n_outcomes))` produces the expected result

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Using `format = "csr"` also produces the expected result.

Comment: Yes, it does. You could try using `y.toarray()` and see what happens. Also, it would be interesting to know if converting `x.T` to a 'csc' matrix before multiplying produces the expected result. But regardless, it seems like a bug.

Comment: `A=(x.T).dot(y)`.  Look at `A.dtype`.  It's object.  The `@` version is `float`.  Or look at `A[0,0]`.  it's (200,400) sparse matrix.  With `(x.T).dot(...)`, the dense interpretation of `dot` is used, with `np.array(y)`.  From the `sparse` docs: **As of NumPy 1.7, np.dot is not aware of sparse matrices, therefore using it will result on unexpected results or errors.**

Comment: Also *"it is **strongly discouraged** to use NumPy functions directly on these matrices because NumPy may not properly convert them for computations, leading to unexpected (and incorrect) results"*

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. So I assume that `(x.T.matmul(y)).shape == (50, 200)`?

Comment: With the `@`, the sparse version of matmul/dot is used.

Comment: @David.  `np.matmul` is a function; not a method  (`dot` has both, `matmul` does not).  It produces an error, since `np.array(y)` is 0d.

Comment: True, thanks! I assumed it had a method as well. Do you know of any logic to when Numpy has a method vs function vs both?

Comment: @David, don't try to use 'logic' to distinguish function from method.  There's a clear syntactic difference between the two in Python.  And always check the documentation.  `numpy` often provides both, but there is a large collection of `ufunc` that are clearly functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@` the sparse definition of matrix multiplication, producing the same thing as the dense equivalent - but a bit faster.

```
In [65]: np.allclose((x.T @ y), x.T.dot(y.A))
Out[65]: True

In [66]: timeit x.T@y
381 µs ± 1.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [67]: timeit x.T.dot(y.A)
521 µs ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

`y.A` is the correct way to convert sparse to dense (`.toarray()`).  `np.array(y)` is wrong.

```
In [68]: timeit x.T.dot(y)
1.69 s ± 210 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Not only is the shape wrong, so is the dtype, and the time is much longer.  When shapes are unexpected, dig further, making sure that dtype, and even element values make sense.

another way to do the calculation correctly

```
In [71]: timeit y.T.dot(x).T
379 µs ± 1.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Testing the `matmul` suggestion:

```
In [75]: np.matmul(x.T,y).shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[75], line 1
----> 1 np.matmul(x.T,y).shape

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

This error is because `np.array(y)` is a 0d object dtype array; just a crude array wrapper around the sparse matrix.  And `matmul`, in contrast to `dot`, can't operate on 0d, scalar, objects or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably worked this out already from our discussion in the comments, but the reason you're seeing this difference is likely because of your use of an operator for `matmul` and a function/method for `dot`. The operator implementation of the calling object is used first. However, if this fails, the equivalent reflected operator of the other operand is called, in this case [`__rmatmul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmatmul__), which is implemented by the sparse matrix. When you call `dot` it always uses the `dot` implementation of the calling object, which fails to deal with the sparse array correctly.